AWS SageMaker Ground Truth job finished successfully without assigning tasks to requested number of human workers
We created a GT labelling job using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/cer-annotation-pdf.html.
We pre-selected ~500 documents and processed them via provided scripts, which yielded ~700 tasks. We also set that we want 3 human workers per task.
After several days, we were surprised that the job finished successfully. When I processed the generated data by loading them into our data lake and processed them, we learned that only ~20 documents were processed by requested 3 workers, ~30 were processed by 2 workers and the rest was processed only by one worker.
I double checked that the job has annotation job has correct settings by checking AWS API and there is NumberOfHumanWorkersPerDataObject: 3 in the configuration.
We checked lambda logs but there is no error, the job also states that everything was processed successfully.
How is it possible that Ground Truth didn't follow requested assignment criteria?

The problem was with this configuration
TaskAvailabilityLifetimeInSeconds: 864000
StoppingConditions:
  MaxPercentageOfInputDatasetLabeled: 100

It seems that since one worker finished all his tasks and there was no action within 10 days from the rest of the workforce pool then entire job was finished.
